# Image warping using mesh

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, graphics, warp

I would like to warp one fisheye image:
Left:

Into this target image:

The target image is actually a part of the synthetic panorama:

I know a method called mesh warping, like:

But how am I able to find or define a irregular mesh like this? Very grateful if someone can give me some suggestions. I would like to have this mesh, so that I can use this mesh for every frame of a video and warp every frame into this target image.

Comment: How is the shape defined ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust it is part of the synthetic panorma. I would like to have the warping method implemented so that I can warp it for other frames in the video.

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @Yves Daoust sorry I mean warp the original image into the target one. I edited it.

Comment: With so little information, I can't help.

Comment: May you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683954/how-can-i-do-image-warp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a one-off project, or are you trying to write an automatic procedure?

If the former, you can just hand-tag corresponding points in the two images till you have enough coverage, particularly in the more "curvy" areas, then warp using (for example) a thin-plate spline defined by the point correspondences. This works iteratively: match some points, warp, figure out where the error is largest, add more point matches there. Doing all this in, say, Matlab or Python+OpenCv is quite easy.

You can then try to automate it using feature extraction and matching. The trouble is you'll need to use both point and line correspondences...

Comment: Thx for replying. It is one-off. My project is to merge 3 fisheye videostreams into one. My thinking is to start from merging 3 fisheye images into one panorama for one frame and then keep the setting for the whole video. Thin-plate spline? I will check it.

Comment: @luzhenzheng1990 you should upvote or accept the answer if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thx for ur answer. I am still new here.